# "Start Developing iOS Apps Today" list not initializing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

FNG, here.

I am working my way through Apple's iOS tutorial. I am about half-way through the last tutorial, having just completed the "Display the Data" subsection. Problem is, no data is displayed.

It appears that the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is not being called, as evidenced by the fact that an `NSLog(@"Here");` added to the method (before the `return cell;` line) creates no output.

Of course, I could start from scratch and simply re-create the thing, but that would lose a valuable learning opportunity. Also, I'd probably create just another error somewhere else.

The app builds and launches fine, just no data is displayed. The `loadInitialData` method is being called.

Also, I'm using Xcode 6.1, which is I think a version beyond the one used in the tutorial, but everything else seems to be fine.

Any tips on how to debug from here greatly appreciated.

Edit: thank you to @Alex and @lefteris and @zisoft for answers and edits. For anyone who has this problem, it turns out I left out the code that put the data into the the array (`[self.toDoItems addObject:anItem]`), which means `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` returns 0, so nothing calls any further `tableView:` methods. I found the answer by searching the documentation for "Table View Data Source" (thanks @Alex) where, through the beginnings of comprehension, I had an "a-ha!".

Comment: may be you missed to set the table view data source.

Comment: as @Alex said, you must also set the UITableView DataSource to your controller. That can be done either with InterFace Builder or in code, by using `self.tableView.datasource = self` and also same for the delegate

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing subscribing to Table View Datasource Protocol

Simply subscribe to `UITableViewDataSource` and in `viewDidLoad` do 
`self.tableView.datasource = self`

Same for `UITableViewDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

The possibilities may be as follows.
You didn't set the table view data source: (A table view data source defines the data loading in the table view).

You can set the table view data source programmatically(in case you creating the table view programmatically) as well as with the storyboard or xib.

In the case of programmatic creation of the table view your class should conforms to the table view data source procol like `<UITableViewDataSource>` and init the data source  like `_yourTableView.dataSource = self;`
Refer this for more info : [Create table view programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW4)

And in the case creating with Storyboard you just need to connect the datasource by Ctrl + drag the table view to the View Controller (or may be view class) in which you have defined the data source methods.
Refer this [Create table view with storyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW2)

This is what a table view data source does in creation of table view:[image]

Another chance for getting your issue may be you are not implementing data source – `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`: method. Implement this method and return the number of cells you need.